# create javascript automatic slider from one element to another

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm new to javascript so apologies if this question sounds "amateur".

[image]

I'm trying to create a javascript slider that moves from first li element to second list element automatically after 2 second until it goes through all nth element.

Here's what I've done for the HTML:

```
 <ul id ="animals">
              <li>dog</li>
              <li>cat</li>
              <li>fish</li>
          </ul>
```

css:

```
ul li{
  display: inline;
}
```

javascript:

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
  var list = document.getElementById("animals")
  var newLI = document.createElement('li');
  newLI.innerHTML = 'cat';
}
</script>
```

so it sort of works like a carousel. What is the best approach to continuing with this task?

Answer (score 1):

A very naive native in javascript implementation could be like this:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-bz9cwi?file=index.js

```
startCarousel();

function startCarousel() {
  var list = document.getElementById("animals");
  var nrOfItems = list.children.length;
  var counter = 0;
  setInterval(()=>{
    list.children[counter].style["display"] = "none";
    counter = (counter + 1) % nrOfItems;
    list.children[counter].style["display"] = "inline";
  }, 1000);
}
```

But you might want to take a look at frameworks like jQuery, bootstrap, ...
They have these things built-in:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/

Comment: that's a very interesting approach @Stif and thanks for taking your time to help me in my javascript journey. My other question though is, how can this possibly be a horizontal slider? Like seen in my picture above where the middle element is always highlighted as say "blue"?

Comment: much like this plementation: https://azmind.com/demo/bootstrap-carousel-multiple-items/

except I'd like the images to be displayed based on which elemen is active. So If 1 is active, display a picture at the top that says ONE in words.